# How to showUserLocation without animation in MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I use this code to convert MKMapView to UIImage:

```
+(UIImage *)imageFromMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView {

    BOOL showsUserLocation = mapView.showsUserLocation; //save flag
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO]; //hide blue bubble for taking picture

    CGRect frame = mapView.frame;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
        ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
        frame.size.width *= 2;
        frame.size.height *= 2;
    }
    //    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((frame.size), YES, 0.0);
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    DLog(@"got mapImage size:%@",NSStringFromCGSize(mapImage.size));

    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:showsUserLocation];//restore flag
    return mapImage;
}
```

I call this method everytime i move MapView center position, so yellow bubble appears with whole animation in every step. It is annoying.

Is it possible to show current user location without animation?

Comment: dont render the map each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: you can't -- not without SOME effort :)

long answer: you can't UNLESS you fake the whole thing and return a blank annotation view for the real location and use the location manager to update another custom annotation.

#### steps:

1 - if `viewForAnnotation` asks for a `UIView` for the `MKUserLocation`, return a blank one but not nil! Use An empty UIView.
 *nil would show the dot.*

**NOW returning ANYTHIN BUT nil from `viewForAnnotation` for the location will disable tracking: this is a serious bug in map kit**

2 - so you need to start the `CLLocationManager` yourself, add an OWN `MKAnnotation` to the `MKMapView` in order to show the userLocation.
*That you can treat like ANY MKAnnotation updating its coordinate whenever `locationDidUpdate` is fired*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, and creating a new offline `MKMapView` with the same region, etc... but without the user location in order to take the snapshot from will probably be much too costly every time the user moves the visible map.